# Get custom header using javascript?

Tags: javascript, http-headers

If I set a custom header using php on the server side like this:

```
header('customheader: yay');
```

How do I receive this on the client side using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to send another request to retrieve the headers. It's often not an issue if the url is cached. In this case, I will recommend you to use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API for the task.

```
fetch('/whatever/url').then(response => console.log(response.headers.get('customheader')));
```

Comment: no IE support https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

use `$.ajax().done()` event `jqXHR` parameter

`jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});`

Then call `getResponseHeader()` on the `jqXHR object` to get a list of response headers

Comment: Is this for a basic http request or just ajax? Looking for a general solution that uses pure javascript.

Comment: jqXHR is a wrapper with added properties, never the less getResponseHeader() is standard https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-getresponseheader()-method